# Remove or disable focus border of browser via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabindex

Does anybody know how to disable or manipulate the (in most browsers) dashed border of a dom-element if it has the focus in a tabindex order?

I want to build my own style for a focused element, but it would be great to use the existing feature, because with tabindex it is possible to bind keydown event to the dom-element.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Just make a CSS rule for the elements you want that have `outline:none;`

Comment: That's quite good, if you click with the mouse on the item that border does not appear anymore but if you navigate through keyboard? How do you highlight the element?

Comment: @coorasse, if you want to only hide it for clicks you will need to use javascript and call `.blur()` on the element once you click it..

Comment: epic short answer :) +1

Comment: **Also consider this article: https://www.sitebase.be/disable-focus-outline-without-breaking-accessibility/ (if you need to design for accessible web !! thanks @Wim Mostmans)**

Comment: @helle glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 45):

CSS trick:

```
:focus { outline: none; }
```

Comment: Important to consider usability issues as soon as you are disabling a accessibility feature native in the browser. I suggest to create your own outline focus, like background color yellow.

Answer (score 5):

With Firefox 53.0, if I disable the outline with one of the proposed solution, Firefox displays the default one.

However, if I use a blank color, it doesn't detect that the outline is hidden:

```css
input:focus{
   outline: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic way is set outline to none:

```
outline: none;
```

However, it didn't work anymore on higher version browser or FireFox.
This trick work for me:

```
outline: 0px solid transparent;
```

LOL. In future, if it detected transparent, then just replace with a little tiny higher transparent:

```
outline: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.001);
```

Some browsers, it was a boxshadow too:

```
outline:none !important;
outline-width: 0 !important;
box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
outline: 0;
}

a: hover,
a: active,
a: focus {
     outline: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:focus state` - Set the [outline property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) to 0px solid transparent;

Answer (score -4):

```
$(function() {
     $('a').click(function() { $(this).blur(); });
     $('input').click(function() { $(this).blur(); });
});
```

Don't use CSS disable focus: http://outlinenone.com/ This use other users.

Comment: why should I not use css? I see the point in your link, but your suggested solution will totally freak out the GUI and you wont be able, to access the fields.

Answer (score -8):

Using jQuery you can do

```
$("#nav li a").focus(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: with blur i lose the focus, isn't it?
so i cannot bind keydown event as well as mousewheel ...

Comment: Right, didn't get the whole question ;)