# CSS: Text input has another border when selected

Tags: html, css

I have an input section for text and I would like the `border-radius` of that input to be `50px`.

However, when I have the `border-radius`, the original border is still visible when that field is selected.

I have added a picture below where you can clearly see what I'm referring to. The light border with radius is what I want, but I am also getting another rectangular border.

Here's the CSS I currently have:

```
            .searchbox {
            
            width: 560px;
            height: 39px;
            border-color: #dedede;
            
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius: 50px;



        }
```

HTML for this is basic input:

```
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchbox">
```

[image: Image attached]

Comment: That's the [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline), not the border

Comment: That's an outline for the input

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015523/remove-or-disable-focus-border-of-browser-via-javascript

Comment: Hi Saj. Please refer to questions i have linked above. You will find plenty of very useful answers which are covered in details for learning as well regarding your question. Happy coding :)

Comment: What you see, is the *outline*. Style it how you'd like it, but please don't remove it entirely without providing an alternative for keyboard users (http://www.outlinenone.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You should add

```
.searchbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```css
.searchbox {
  width: 560px;
  height: 39px;
  border-color: #dedede;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.searchbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchbox">
```

---

**Reference**

[:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Comment: Please do not use `outline: none`. (http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `outline: none;` to the `:focus` styles.

## Never do this!

Some people navigate webpages with the tab key on their keyboard because they can't use a mouse. The outlines around elements help them see what they are focusing on. You are basically confusing them if you do this.

So you should definitely do something else on focus, such as change the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.searchbox:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

to your CSS

Comment: Please do not use `outline: none`. (http://www.outlinenone.com/)